# How filter list parents by conditional children

Tags: c#

sorry for the bad writing...
I have the following scenario in an mvc project.
I have an object that has a list type property and that property also contains a list type child.
How can I get the List1 object where List2 children have cod = 2 and List3 children have cod = 9.

```
   public class List1
    {
        public int cod {get;set;}
        public List<List2> list2 {get;set;}
    }

    public class List2
    {
        public int cod {get; set;}
        public List<List3> list3 {get;set;}

    }

    public class List3
    {
        public int cod {get;set;}
    }

    var list1 = new List1() { cod = 1 };
    list1.list2 = new List<List2>();
    list1.list2.Add(new List2
            {
                cod = 1,
                list3 = new List<List3>(){
                new List3{cod = 1},
                new List3{cod = 2}             
            },

            });

            list1.list2.Add(new List2
            {
                cod = 2,
                list3 = new List<List3>(){
                new List3{cod = 7},
                new List3{cod = 8},
                new List3{cod = 9}
            },

            });
            list1.list2.Add(new List2
            {
                cod = 2,
                list3 = new List<List3>(){
                new List3{cod = 7},            
                new List3{cod = 9},
                new List3{cod = 9}
            },

            });


            listFather.Add(list1);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Could you please clarify in more detail; from what object per say (where's `listFather` coming from), I understand a bit, but can you please show expected output please? We could do this a few different ways, `linq`, `foreach` etc. do you mind showing us what you have tried and what isn't working so we can better help you.

Comment: Hello @Çöđěxěŕ, tks! i expect the object List 1 with 2 childrens List2, and the childrens List3 que tenham cod=9

Comment: thanks for the update, it seems you found your answer.

Comment: My example https://dotnetfiddle.net/aw5oku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets me give a try:

```
var list = listFather.Select(c => new List1
{
cod = c.cod,
list2 = c.list2.Select(d => new List2
{
cod = d.cod,
list3 = d.list3.Where(x => x.cod == 9).ToList()

}).Where(r => r.cod == 2).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: To be honest, not explaining your solution isn't helpful; especially if OP or anyone else that see's this may not be familiar with `linq`. Updating the post to include relevant details would support this answer better.

Comment: For sure, I gonna try explain, tks for the advice

Answer (score 5):

I think this version would be far easier to understand:

```
// How can I get the List1 object,
// where List2 children have cod = 2,
// and List3 children have cod = 9.

var matches = (from l1 in listFather
              from l2 in l1.list2
              from l3 in l2.list3
              where l2.cod == 2 &&
                    l3.cod == 9
              select l1).Distinct();
```

You'll get the same instance of List1 added for each time it has a List2/List3 combination that matches, thus the `Distinct()` call on the end so that each particular instance is only listed once in your results.

Here's a full example:

```
public class List1
{
    public int cod { get; set; }
    public List<List2> list2 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("l1-cod: " + cod);
        foreach(List2 l2 in list2)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(l2.ToString());
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

}

public class List2
{
    public int cod { get; set; }
    public List<List3> list3 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("\tl2-cod: " + cod);
        foreach (List3 l3 in list3)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("\t\t" + l3.ToString());
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public class List3
{
    public int cod { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "l3-cod: " + cod;
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<List1> listFather = new List<List1>();

        var listA = new List1() { cod = 1 };
        listA.list2 = new List<List2>();
        listA.list2.Add(new List2
        {
            cod = 1,
            list3 = new List<List3>(){
            new List3{cod = 1},
            new List3{cod = 2}
        },

        });

        listA.list2.Add(new List2
        {
            cod = 2,
            list3 = new List<List3>(){
            new List3{cod = 7},
            new List3{cod = 8},
            new List3{cod = 9}
        },

        });
        listA.list2.Add(new List2
        {
            cod = 2,
            list3 = new List<List3>(){
            new List3{cod = 7},
            new List3{cod = 9},
            new List3{cod = 9}
        },

        });
        listFather.Add(listA);

        var listB = new List1() { cod = 2 };
        listB.list2 = new List<List2>();
        listB.list2.Add(new List2
        {
            cod = 1,
            list3 = new List<List3>(){
            new List3{cod = 1},
            new List3{cod = 2}
        },

        });

        listB.list2.Add(new List2
        {
            cod = 2,
            list3 = new List<List3>(){
            new List3{cod = 7},
            new List3{cod = 8},
            new List3{cod = 10}
        },

        });
        listFather.Add(listB);

        var listC = new List1() { cod = 5 };
        listC.list2 = new List<List2>();
        listC.list2.Add(new List2
        {
            cod = 4,
            list3 = new List<List3>(){
            new List3{cod = 6},
            new List3{cod = 7}
        },

        });

        listC.list2.Add(new List2
        {
            cod = 2,
            list3 = new List<List3>(){
            new List3{cod = 7},
            new List3{cod = 8},
            new List3{cod = 10}
        },

        });
        listFather.Add(listC);

        var listD = new List1() { cod = 7 };
        listD.list2 = new List<List2>();
        listD.list2.Add(new List2
        {
            cod = 8,
            list3 = new List<List3>(){
            new List3{cod = 1},
            new List3{cod = 2}
        },

        });

        listD.list2.Add(new List2
        {
            cod = 2,
            list3 = new List<List3>(){
            new List3{cod = 7},
            new List3{cod = 9},
            new List3{cod = 1}
        },

        });
        listFather.Add(listD);

        Console.WriteLine("All objects:");            
        foreach(List1 l1 in listFather)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(l1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("----------");

        // How can I get the List1 object,
        // where List2 children have cod = 2,
        // and List3 children have cod = 9.
        var matches = (from l1 in listFather
                      from l2 in l1.list2
                      from l3 in l2.list3
                      where l2.cod == 2 &&
                            l3.cod == 9
                      select l1).Distinct();

        Console.WriteLine("All matches:");
        foreach (List1 l1 in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(l1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.Write("Press Enter to quit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
All objects:
l1-cod: 1
        l2-cod: 1
                l3-cod: 1
                l3-cod: 2

        l2-cod: 2
                l3-cod: 7
                l3-cod: 8
                l3-cod: 9

        l2-cod: 2
                l3-cod: 7
                l3-cod: 9
                l3-cod: 9


l1-cod: 2
        l2-cod: 1
                l3-cod: 1
                l3-cod: 2

        l2-cod: 2
                l3-cod: 7
                l3-cod: 8
                l3-cod: 10


l1-cod: 5
        l2-cod: 4
                l3-cod: 6
                l3-cod: 7

        l2-cod: 2
                l3-cod: 7
                l3-cod: 8
                l3-cod: 10


l1-cod: 7
        l2-cod: 8
                l3-cod: 1
                l3-cod: 2

        l2-cod: 2
                l3-cod: 7
                l3-cod: 9
                l3-cod: 1


----------
All matches:
l1-cod: 1
        l2-cod: 1
                l3-cod: 1
                l3-cod: 2

        l2-cod: 2
                l3-cod: 7
                l3-cod: 8
                l3-cod: 9

        l2-cod: 2
                l3-cod: 7
                l3-cod: 9
                l3-cod: 9


l1-cod: 7
        l2-cod: 8
                l3-cod: 1
                l3-cod: 2

        l2-cod: 2
                l3-cod: 7
                l3-cod: 9
                l3-cod: 1



Press Enter to quit
```